# jquery: how to change text on button when click and when is clicked

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

i have this button who send a form via ajax (without change page)

```
<button name="btn_invio" id="btn_invio-<?=$id_hotel?>" type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-sm shadow-none" style="margin-top:5px; margin-left:5px; margin-right:5px; width:100%;">Send</button>
```

Now i change the text when user click on the button so the button change from "send" to "sending..."

```
$("#btn_invio-<?=$id_hotel?>").click(function(){
$('#btn_invio-<?=$id_hotel?>').html('Sending...');
});
```

This is working

Now i want to show again the word "send" (for send another message) after the form is sent

How i can do it?
Thank you

Comment: Do the same thing from the callback of your Ajax call

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a [submit](https://api.jquery.com/submit/) event for your form. Then `$.ajax`. Something like:

```
$("#yourForm").submit(function(e) {

    e.preventDefault(); // avoid to execute the actual submit of the form.

    var form = $(this);
    var actionUrl = form.attr('action');

    $('#btn_invio-<?=$id_hotel?>').html('Sending...');
    
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: actionUrl,
        data: form.serialize(), // serializes the form's elements.
        success: function(data)
        {
          $('#btn_invio-<?=$id_hotel?>').html('Send');

        }
    });
    
});
```

Comment: ok, now the button work, but how i can show the message "message sent" under the button?

Before i had this div:
<div id="invio-preventivo-<?=$id_hotel?>" align="center" style="margin-top:10px;"></div>

Comment: in part i solved it, i added this:

 $('#invio-preventivo-<?=$id_hotel?>').html('<span class="green">Preventivo Inviato</span>');

in the success function, but i want to show the message i add in my php file, so if the message have not error, i show "Preventivo Inviato!", if something go wrong i have a red alert with error message.

How i can show the message from the php file?

Comment: `data` contains a response message. Show it using `html` and prepare a correct message in your php file

Comment: i not undestand...

My php file is a phpmailer script, so at the end of the file i have:

$mail->AltBody = 'Text not html';

    $mail->send();
 
    echo "<span class=\"green\">Message Sent!</span>";
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "<span class=\"red\">Ops, error: {$mail->ErrorInfo}</span>";
}

Now i want to show this message on my data function, how i can do?

Comment: Try to use `$('#yourID').html(data)` in `success`

Comment: wow, yes, now is working, thank you very much!!!

Comment: Please vote up  my answer if I help you :)

Comment: how? i click on the arrow up, but i do not if is ok for you. Can you explane me if is ok??

Comment: Yeah. Accepting of the answer is fine. Thanks :)